# remove all active sessions for given uid

Tags: users

How to remove all active sessions for given uid who has logged in from different browsers or apps.

I used

```
drupal_session_destroy_uid($uid);
drupal_session_regenerate();
```

but old sessions still valid and user can create content from apps having that sessions.

I need to delete all sessions for that user and create new one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just delete the corresonding entries from the sessions table? e.g.
in sql, `delete from sessions where uid = <uid>`

This won't work if you're using memcache for your sessions table, but I imagine there's an equivalent if you are.

Comment: It comes to my mind but I need a solution based on drupal api to cope with all situations and not to bypass hook_user_logout invoking, Your answer is highly appreciated